# Wkhtmltopdf fails to resolve host when executed from php

Tags: php, windows, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I'm generating pdf from php using wkhtmltopdf, but I have peculiar problem. When the template doesn't use any external sources everything is fine. But when it imports anything over http/file protocol I get:

```
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: ""
stdout: "Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
[=======> ] 13%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6) 
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6) 
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6) 
Printing pages (6/6)
[> ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done 
Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError
```

Exception tells me that:
`command: "D:\Programs\wkhtmlpdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --lowquality "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy54d3831ed861e8.25642951.html" "C:\Windows\Temp\D60C.tmp".`

In this case it was `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);` which caused this error, but I simply can't use any link if I want it to work from php. When run from command line, everything is ok. I've checked that php executes it from "SYSTEM" user, so I spawned myself a cmd window running as SYSTEM, and the pdf was created without any problems. Allow_url_fopen is enabled, openssl as well.

I'm using KnpSnappyBundle which uses Knp snappy library, which uses wkhtmltopdf. 
I've read all wkhtmltopdf related problems on SO, but couldn't find an answer.

PHP 5.5.5, apache 2.4.4

Thank you

Update: It seems symfony console component does some magic with proc_open.

`$this->process = proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $this->env, $this->options);`

And the parameters var_dump is

```
string(227) "cmd /V:ON /E:ON /C "("D:\Programs\wkhtmlpdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --lowquality "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy54d3949bd6e035.20793656.html" "C:\Windows\Temp\2627.tmp") 1>"C:\Windows\Temp\sf_26C4.tmp" 2>"C:\Windows\Temp\sf_26C5.tmp""" 
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(4) "pipe" 
        [1]=> string(1) "r" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(4) "file" 
        [1]=> string(3) "NUL" 
        [2]=> string(1) "w" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(4) "file" 
        [1]=> string(3) "NUL" 
        [2]=> string(1) "w" 
    } 
} array(0) {

} string(24) "D:\Web\e-diagnostyka\web" array(0) {

} array(3) {
    ["suppress_errors"]=> bool(true) 
    ["binary_pipes"]=> bool(true) 
    ["bypass_shell"]=> bool(true) 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem. It started occurring after I ran a composer update.

The problem is in the latest release of the KnpLabs/snappy repository.

Reverting back to an earlier release (0.3.1) of this repository fixed the problem for me.

For a more detailed look at the changes made that are causing the problem, see: [KnpLabs/snappy version changes](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/compare/523d410...4d46c5d)

Hope it helped. :)